# unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file blade component

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade

I'm trying to dynamically change the classes depending on the route in laravel, however using this:

```
<x-ui.general.dashboard_link href="/dashboard/calendar" @if ("hello" == "hello") class="text-sm" @endif>CALENDAR</x-ui.general.dashboard_link>
```

I get "syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file", all @if and @endif's are closed and have the correct tags, this only occurs on blade component tags. Why?

Comment: Your code (the `@if ... @endif`) works just fine for me and doesn't trigger that error... You could try this with a Ternary: `class="{{ 'hello' == 'hello' ? 'text-sm' ? '' }}"` and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel's Blade templating engine, Blade directives like `@if`, `@else`, `@endif`, etc., are not directly compatible inside Blade components when you're passing in attributes or props like `href` or `class`.

Instead, you can use PHP's ternary conditional operator as a workaround, or set a variable before the component:

```
<x-ui.general.dashboard_link href="/dashboard/calendar" :class="('hello' == 'hello') ? 'text-sm' : ''">CALENDAR</x-ui.general.dashboard_link>
```

Comment: This answer needs better explanation, it is not just "using a ternary as a workaround." Explain the additional code and features you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is due the fact that you cannot use blade directives such as `@if` and `@endif` within the attributes of a blade component. Instead, you can use a ternary operator to conditionally set the class attribute like this:

```
<x-ui.general.dashboard_link href="/dashboard/calendar" :class="('hello' == 'hello') ? 'text-sm' : ''">CALENDAR</x-ui.general.dashboard_link>
```